# Extracting the last digit of a number

Tags: string, r, digits

Suppose this is the data:

```
2011/03/06,17:24:17.100,EUR/USD,1.40200,3000000
```

I want to extract the last digit of the price, even if it is zero. Here is the code:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
types<-list(date="TEXT",time="TEXT",curr="TEXT",price="TEXT",volume="INTEGER")
mydata=read.table("data.out", sep="," , header=FALSE)
setnames(mydata, names(types))
str_sub(mydata$price,start=-1)
```

this is the result: "2", it ignores zeros. I read the price as a text so I should get "0".

EDIT, Thanks to jlhoward:

mydata<-read.table(...) is converting the price and volume columns to numeric automatically. I used mydata<- read.table(...,colClasses="character"), problem solved.

Comment: If your data is following this format, then separate the line by comma, get the second last item, and use str[-1] to get the last digit

Comment: Make sure you really understand what "last digit" means, since a number (as opposed to a string) has arbitrary digits.  If you want the "ones" digit, then  `x%%10` will return the "ones" digit of any number.

Comment: I suspect that `mydata<-read.table(...)` is converting your `price` and `volume` columns to numeric automatically. If you want to read everything as text, use `mydata<- read.table(...,colClasses="character")`. Then the rest of your code should work.

Comment: @jlhoward, brilliant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't stating where your data come from.  If you use `read.csv` on a file, you'll have the items separated into columns immediately.  You can even get them from the keyboard, e.g.:

```
read.csv(stdin(),header=FALSE)
0: 300,hello,40.2
1: 
#   V1    V2   V3
# 1 300 hello 40.2
```

Then you could do `foo<- dat$V3%%10` , as in my comment above, to get the last digit.

Comment: It worked with some changes, (mydata$price*100000)%%10, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I talked about in the comment.

```
   line = "2011/03/06,17:24:17.100,EUR/USD,1.40200,3000000"
    sp = line.split(",")
    sp
    ['2011/03/06', '17:24:17.100', 'EUR/USD', '1.40200', '3000000']
    price = sp[-2]
    price
    '1.40200'
    last = price[-1]
    last
    '0'
```

Comment: But the data itself is very big, it is not easy to handle in this way.

Comment: @Soheil I haven't found any solution for dealing with the ending 0 when reading the data, if I were you, I would do this in this method (if it is urgent). It is done by reading the file line by line, and for each line, the processing time isn't long.

Comment: @YilunZhang see my suggestions.  Why use 'split' when `read.csv` does it all for you?